# WKWebView Video Player replaces UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview, swift5

when i play a youtube video livestream with `WKWebView` apples default video player presents. If i dismiss it and want to show a different `ViewController` it doesn't detect my `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` of my Application anymore! It says it is a normal `UIViewController` (The `ViewController` of the `WebView`). I need my NavController!

This does not happen when the Video Player from Apple does not present.

This is how I replace the UINavigationControllers vcs:

(I am using a SideMenu)

```swift
if let navView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    navView.viewControllers = [viewC]
    dismiss(animated: true)
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is how i load a youtube video livestream:

```swift
webView.isOpaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = .clear

let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
webView.load(req)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My device is jailbroken and with that i could use picture in picture that is recognized as a `ViewController` that was the issue